# Contiki-NG: tsch network creation takes a really long time

Tags: c, embedded, iot, contiki, contiki-ng

Im currently developing a low power IoT node based on a TI CC1350 launchpad board. I'm using Contiki-NG with tsch to let the nodes connect to themselves and the network coordinator.

My problem is that the first connection between a node and the coordinator takes way too long (in the 10s of minutes) which makes debugging the network near impossible as each time a node is reset I have to wait a long time before trying my changes.

Is there any settings I could change in the contiki configuration to allow the connection to happen more quickly?

Comment: 1) How many channel do you have in the hopping sequence? 2) Once connected, do you get most packets delivered, or experience a large number of unacked packets?

Comment: So, I'm using the default 4 channels, sequence length 4 in tsch config. What are the advantages of switching to other sequences? Once connected I receive packets correctly almost 100% of the time, no problem there

Comment: I have experienced similar problems with other CC26xx/CC13xx chips and never quite found the source of the problem. I found that adding a busywait in the TSCH scanning code helps and also reducing or increasing the TSCH_CONF_ASSOCIATION_POLL_FREQUENCY constant helps. It's best to test on a single channel hopping sequence so you're sure the receiver is always on the right channel.

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you share a bit of code on how to add the busywait and what values I could set the TSCH_CONF_ASSOCIATION_POLL_FREQUENCY to?

Comment: as for waiting, try a simple busywait:  `RTIMER_BUSYWAIT(RTIMER_SECOND / 100);`. If I had a clear answer what the polling frequency, I would write an answer instead of a comment.